# Blender tapered stroke

Tags: texture-painting

I would like to paint in Blender  tapered stroke on a mesh like this

[image]

I can make this in Inkscape but is there a way to make this in Blender so that I could make free hand tapered stroke ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle the pressure settings in the paint tool bar for Radius and untoggle Strength so that you get a varied width but constant strength to your stroke. Enable Smooth Stroke either by toggle or pressing Shift+S, and possibly increase the samples to the stroke. This enables you to see the stroke lag behind the cursor and helps you round the stroke.

This is for freehand strokes - if you use the Curve Stroke tool and set up the path beforehand, there isn't a way yet to vary the width along the curve - it will evenly stroke along that curve.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a textured stroke in stencil mode, use your texture as a stamp and paint your premade curves.

Or use a texture in the shape of your needed sharp stroke and combine with Craig D Jones answer.